# ASP.NET MVC - HtmlHelper and Session data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to create a helper that searches through session data, Preferably something like this:

```
public static bool CheckForModerator(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    return Session["isAdmin"];
}
```

But i cannot access Session[] data. I tried looking through `htmlHelper`, but i cannot find Session there either. What do i need to do in order to access Session data?

Comment: try Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Session["isAdmin"]) instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
using System.Web;
```

and then

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
return context.Session["isAdmin"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Prefer `(bool)htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Session["IsAdmin"]`

Comment: this answer is better, since it's ASP.NET Core compatible

Answer (score 2):

Try getting it from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session`